# Linq to SQL: Load default field Values ONLY for fields with NULL value

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq-to-SQL for a table which got records named ***Category*** and Record has a column  which named ***Level*** which its default value defined -1 through Database declarations.
I want my C# application act like this for Inserting new record R of type Category:

1. if field *Level*  of Variable R is null:use default DB values for
   insertion
2. if filed *Level*  of Variable R is defined (NOT NULL):use value of
   this field for insertion

I have used ***Auto Generated*** property for field ***Level*** but it will cause using default Values for all cases of insertion.

Comment: have you tried adding the default value in the model constructor?

Comment: why don't you simply place a check before saving i.e. `if(obj.Level==null || obj.Level==0){obj.Level=1;}`

Comment: @ManishMishra - because that defeats the purpose of database defaults

Comment: Sounds like a simple if/else situation.  What's the part causing you difficutly?

Comment: @oerkelens wat u mean? he already has set default value in the database, he wants to do it through code

Comment: I might have misread something. If you insert Level = `NULL`, then on insert it should automatically generate the DB default, so i am now at a loss as to what the question is...

Comment: @DanBracuk, I read those two points, and I don't think there is any way you can retrieve database default value. Only thing he can do is to set a default value in Constructor or, make that field nullable

Comment: i think i missed something! C# wont leave field to be null. During INITILIZATION of Record instances, values of field will be set to something. e.g. 0 for int type. So value wont be null. However the main question would be how to use DB default for field in special cases? e.g. i intentionally put NULL values inside field to froce load DB defaults.... I want to know is it possible to do this?

Comment: `yourClass.Field = null;` ?

Comment: setting field to null is not a problem! loading default values from db is the concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq2SQL does not support SQL Default values at all, so there isn't any "built-in" way to do this.
However you could always go and find out the default value of the column in SQL:

```
select DefaultValue=Column_default from from information_schema.columns where column_name='Level' and table_name='Category'
```

You could execute that command on app startup and store the value (converted to the correct type of course) for later use:

```
if (newCategoryToInsert.level==0) 
{
   newCategoryToInsert.level = levelDefaultValueThatIStoredEarlier;
}
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

and use that in Dan's approach.

But if possible, don't bother with any of this and just accept that `NULL` is a good default value for an undefined Level, change the schema to allow `NULL` for "`Level`" and refresh your DBML, then you just don't have to worry about it any more.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of structure should work.

```
if (R.Level == null)
linq query that does not include R.Level.  Database will apply default value
else
linq query that includes R.Level
```

Comment: i'm using below context:    `dbContext.Categories.InsertOnSubmit(newCategoryToInsert);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();` however i don't know how to apply this template to this piece of code